# ErrorException Array to string conversion when Attaching

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a many to many relationship between two tables: atentions and procedimientos. it looks like this[image]

As you can see, my pivot table has 2 extra columns, cantidad, and descuento, along with the keys from both tables.
However, when i try to insert data in that table, i get the error message *ErrorException
Array to string conversion* and if i format those values using json_encode, i get the following

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '["1","1"]' for column `dentalg`.`atencion_procedimientos`.`cantidad` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `atencion_procedimientos` (`atencion_id`, `cantidad`, `created_at`, `descuento`, `procedimientos_id`, `updated_at`) values (11, ["1","1"], 2020-05-06 02:19:20, ["1","1"], 1, 2020-05-06 02:19:20), (11, ["1","1"], 2020-05-06 02:19:20, ["1","1"], 2, 2020-05-06 02:19:20))
```

**This is my store function**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request,[
            'asunto' => 'required',
            'cantidad' => 'required',
            'descuento' => 'required',
            'total_pago' => 'required'
        ]);

        if(Auth::user()->role_id ==1 or Auth::user()->role_id==2){

            $atencion = new Atencion();
            $atencion->doctor_id = Auth::id();
            $atencion->pacientes_id = $request->paciente_id;
            $atencion->asunto = $request->asunto;
            $atencion->tipo_pago = 0; //Tratar de Modificar
            $atencion->estado_pago = 0;
            $atencion->observaciones = $request->observaciones;
            $atencion->total = $request->total_pago;
            $atencion->save();

            $atencion->procedimientos()->attach($request->procedimientos_id,[
                'cantidad' => $request->cantidad,
                'descuento' => $request->cantidad,
            ]);

            Toastr::success('Tratamiento añadido con éxito','success');
            return redirect()->route('admin.Atenciones.index');




        } else {
            Toastr::error('You are not authorized to do this operation','Error');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
```

**Models**

```
public function procedimientos(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Procedimientos')->withPivot('cantidad', 'descuento')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

and

```
public function atenciones(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Atencion')->withPivot('cantidad', 'descuento')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Comment: `2020-05-06 02:19:20` is not a timestamp, it's interpreted as 2020 minus 5 minus 6 etc

Comment: It's clear that `$request->cantidad` is an array and DB is expecting integer. Very self-explanatory error.

Comment: I manage to solve this by using a for loop to insert each element one by one, but i believe there can be a more efficient way to do this